# How to ignore errors about html tags in JMeter when using XPath Extractor

Tags: jmeter

I successfully added an XPath Extractor to my JMeter test.  Now, I am receiving errors in the JMeter.log complaining about 2 of the html tags for one of our web pages.  These tags are created by us and are tags that are ok for us to use in our code.  But, JMeter does not like them.  Is there somewhere that I can enter these tags to let JMeter know to exclude checking them.

Let's say the tags were:

xxxxx
and
xxxxx

Here is the JMeter log info:

2014/01/29 14:27:18 WARN  - jmeter.util.XPathUtil: Tidy errors: line 25 column 4 - Error:  is not recognized!
line 255 column 18 - Error:  is not recognized!
InputStream: Doctype given is ""
InputStream: Document content looks like HTML 4.01 Transitional
33 warnings, 2 errors were found!
This document has errors that must be fixed before
using HTML Tidy to generate a tidied up version.

If I disable the XPath Extractor in my test, I no longer get these errors.  So, I know the XPath Extractor brought this on.  But, I need the XPath Extractor in order to get some other information necessary to run the test.  So, I cannot remove that.  Any ideas how I can ignore these 2 new errors?

I have used an HTML Assertion before and set the Error Threshhold to 2 for a different project.  But, that did not seem to help here.

*Edit: Also, I checked "Use Tidy" for the "XML Parsing Options" on the XPath Extractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `WARN` level of your error it looks like that you have checked `Show warnings` or `Report Errors` or both.

If your page isn't XHTML/XML compliant you'll need to have `Use Tidy` checked.

If your server response is "too broken" from Tidy point of view you can always consider following post processors to get required data:

- [Regular Expressions Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) - which doesn't care about wrong or invalid markup
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) - which uses different selectors and doesn't require page to be XML/XHTML compliant.

In general I would suggest to check page using [HTML Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Assertion) as situation described looks like a real issue to me. Page which is severely broken might happen to be incorrectly rendered, not picked up by search engines, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I had already done an HTML Assertion on a similar page and found a bug which probably also exists here ( you're right ). Also, I could not get the Regular Expression Extractor to return the data I required from a post response when I attempted to use it.  I had to use the XPath Extractor because it was the only one I could get to properly work...lol - see this: ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436338/how-can-i-get-the-value-from-a-hidden-input-field-using-jmeter ). That solution lead to this problem...lol.  I will try the other suggestions listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitri's answer was already correct.  I just wanted to add what I did to solve my issue as it may help someone else.

I ended up using the regular expression extractor successfully ( FINALLY :-) ).  I stumbled upon this page which is EXTREMELY helpful:

```
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html
( section 20.2 )
```

So, in JMeter, I added a Regular Expression Extractor as a child to the HTTP Request I was trying to pull the information from.  Then, my new best friends are the XPath Tester and RegExp Tester under the View Results Tree.  This makes it much easier to quickly test if your expressions are right or wrong.  I ended up with this in the Regular Expression field of the Regular Expression Extractor:

```
name="token" value="(.+?)"
```

What else I realized, for those reading this in the future, is that you can build up to an expression if one of the expressions you find online do not work for you.  Of course, I found mine from that page, but I also found how I could build up to it if I was not this lucky.   What do I mean?

Before I found that section in the JMeter site showing the examples, I tried this:

```
1. Ran my test
2. Looked at View Results Tree I added to the HTTP Request I was trying to pull the value from
3. In the View Results Tree, I clicked on drop down to change it to RegExp Tester
4. Started typing in many things to see what would match and not match into the RegExp Tester.  I tried:
4a. id="token" and this retrieved information
4b. id="token"/@value and this did not retrieve anything
4c. name="token" and this retrieved information
4d. name="token" value="(.+?)" and this retrieved the data I was after
```

Hope this helps someone!